# How to translate text in a html-text?

Tags: python, localization, pyqt, translation

I have a text field in html. The inserted text is formatted with things like lists, underline, tables and such. Using pylupdate4, I want to translate this stuff. Can I wrap a `self.tr("""all the html stuff""")`around it and translate it? Looking into the .ts-file, the parts look very weird:

```
    <message>
        <location filename="Main.py" line="3526"/>
        <source><byte value="xd"/>
&lt;br&gt;<byte value="xd"/>
&lt;p align=&quot;left&quot;, style=&quot;margin-left: 20px; margin-right:20px; margin-top:20px;&quot;&gt;<byte value="xd"/>
test text ipsum blabla ... and so on tbc. <byte value="xd"/>
laurem ipsum blub rocknroll.&lt;br&gt;<byte value="xd"/>
Moreover, Elvis is among us and jackson is his son PNEIS.&lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;<byte value="xd"/>;</source>
        <translation type="unfinished"></translation>
    </message>
```

What is a good approch to translate this? Inside of a big string """...""" I can't type `self.tr`...

Comment: Translate it to what?

Comment: to another language, with `self.tr`...